# Taking a value from json array using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
$.getJSON("./data/revenue-item-data.php",{val:'val'},function(data){

 $('#totalUnits').val(data[0].SUM(item_qty));
     $('#totalAmounts').val(data[0].SUM(DISTINCT net_total));


 });
```

Here is array I get for above code:

```
 [{"SUM(item_qty)":"68","SUM(DISTINCT net_total)":"42753"}]
```

How to display these 2 values (68 , 42753) in #totalUnits & #totalAmounts.This code does not display any thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call `data[0].SUM(item_qty)` as it treats `SUM` as a method. Try this.

```
data[0]['SUM(DISTINCT net_total)']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#totalUnits').val(data["SUM(item_qty)"]);
$('#totalAmounts').val(data["SUM(DISTINCT net_total)"]);
```